# Write rows on destination even when an error occurs?

Tags: sql-server, service, ssis, etl, integration

I'm working on a SSIS project in which there are several steps.

One of those steps is a query, making some modifications to the data, and then it inserts values into several tables.

My problem is that I want all the data to be inserted, ignoring some problem that may rise from this, like primary keys, etc. I also have configured a mail notification in case this happens, which is working, but the data keeps truncating in a exception when the data is being written.

[image: Actual layout]

I've tried configuring on "ignore failure", and got nothing.

I also tried another solutions that other users have posted (like this post:

[SSIS 2005 - Ignore row insert failures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775069/ssis-2005-ignore-row-insert-failures) )

I've tried

[image: this]

Problem state (doesn't finish processing):

[image: Here]

This wrote 500 lines, failed on the 501 and that's it, doesn't even finish the process.

Any suggestions will help

Comment: For failures you have to have another line in your data flow to output the failed rows to a different table (generic one with all NVARCHAR or something so you dont have data issues.  Though sounds like you have PKs and other things and you want to insert ignoring these.  To do this you should import to stage table, then write an SP that will do the inserts and you can write queries that will only insert valid data or even write it so it inserts into required tables first so you dont have PK/FK issues.

Comment: I've tried that and the result doesn't change, i've tried to redirect to a `SELECT 1 ` in a OLE DB destination and did not work, same problem.